# How to pass a value to a function in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I created a `StatefulWidget` and get the index value here:

[image]

But the index is not accessible in the function, how can I access the index in the Fetchingredient function.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Write `widget` before index. Final code:

```
widget.index
```